# Posterior on probability of a biased coin

Tags: probability

I have a biased coin with probability of heads of $p>1/2$. I know the true value of $p$ but you do not.

You have a prior distribution on the true value of $p$ which I also know. This could be constructed, for example, by me flipping the coin a number of times and both of us observing the outcomes. Assume that the prior takes the form of a beta distribution, Beta$(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ where $\alpha_0$ ($\beta_0$) is the number of heads (tails) in this initial set of outcomes.

I then give the coin to you and you privately flip it $n$ times, updating your posterior after each flip. I do **not** see the outcomes of these flips. What can I say about your posterior as a function of $n$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what sort of answer you're looking for with "What can I say". You can calculate the posterior in dependence on the unknown outcomes of the flips. Or do you mean something more along the lines of "Can I say that it will be more peaked, less peaked, or the like?"

Comment: @joriki Anything really, both quantitative and qualitative. I know the set of possible posteriors, and their respective likelihoods (using my knowledge of $p$), after you flip $n$ times (side question: is this a standard mathematical object? Like an "expected posterior"?). Also, I know in the limit that your posterior will become sharper around the true value of $p$, but I would like to get more insight into how fast this happens as a function of some properties of the Bernoulli distribution, i.e. the variance.

Comment: When you say "update the posterior", do you simply mean the following?  E.g. initially there were 3 Heads and 2 Tails, so we start with Beta(3,2).  Then $n=3$ and the $n$ secret flips happen to be all Heads, so we end with Beta(6,2)?  If so, the Beta() part of it seems almost irrelevant, and we're just characterizing a sort of random walk on the 2-D plane.

Comment: @antkam Yes, that is how the posterior is updated. The person updating the posterior does not know the true value of $p$, but both players know that as they take more samples they get a more accurate estimate of $p$, i.e., the Beta distribution gets sharper around the true value of $p$ -- I'm not sure if this aspect can be captured with a random walk?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  I simply meant that if you start with $Beta(a,b)$ and do $n$ more flips, then you end with $Beta(a+K, b+n-K)$ where $K \sim Binomial(n, p)$, so in a sense the 2-D point $(a,b)$ "randomly walks" to $(a+K, b+n-K)$ in a simple process where the point moves rightward with prob $p$ and upward with prob $1-p$, for $n$ steps.  If you have specific questions, e.g. how fast the mean of Beta approaches $p$, or how fast the variance of Beta shrinks, as functions of $n$, maybe those can be calculated...